# Probability/Linearity of expectation - Foxes and Hounds

Tags: probability

I came across this question on a probability problems app I found. Can't seem to get my head around it.

"Five foxes and seven hounds run into a foxhole. While they're inside they get all jumbled up, so that all orderings are equally likely.

The foxes and hounds run out of the hole in a neat line. On average, how many foxes are immediately followed by a hound?"

The given hint: Linearity of expectation will help:
frame the foxes 1,2..,5, and X_i be an indicator of whether a fox is followed by a hound. The answer is E[X_1 + ... + X_5] = E[X_1] + .. E[X_5].

I tried to individually frame each term in the aforementioned formula but I can't seem to get it right. The approach was something like this.

So for the first time I assumed a situation where there exists only one such fox-hound pair(let a be foxes and b be hounds):

bbbbbbaaaa ab.

Which is equivalent to calculating the unique ways to place one object in 11 distinguishable boxes. And so on for other number of pairs.

I also tried an approach where I calculated all the orderings with 1,2..5 pairs, i.e, "fox followed by a hound" instances, multiplied them with the respective number of pairs and divided by the total number of possible pairings, however, I wasn't able to get the right answer.

Any hints or direction towards the right approach(s) are appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: The hint is perfectly fine. You should explain/include what you did and why it wasn't "right". I assume this means you know what the right answer is. You should include that too in case it is wrong. Also include what you did using the other method. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: I meant [edit] your post and include your work that way. Also, if you want respondents to be able to read your work, it's best you become familiar with MathJax. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @probablyme - Oh ok, sure. Sorry about that. I'm new here.

Comment: The linearity hints mean that you can just focus on a particular fox without simultaneously considering all other permutation, which simplify the problem. You calculate the expectation of each indicator, which is the probability of ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $X_i$ be the indicator function that canid #$i$ out of the hole is a fox and followed by a hound.

Then the average count of canids who are a fox and followed by a hound is: $\mathsf E(\sum_{i=1}^{12}X_i)$

We note that the 12th canid *cannot* be followed by any other (end of line), but for all 11 other foxes $\mathsf E(X_i)=\mathsf P(X_i=1)= \tfrac 5{12}\cdot\tfrac 7{11}$.   Then the Linearity of Expectation says, "The expectation of the sum is the sum of the expectations!"

> $$\mathsf E(\sum_{i=1}^{12}X_i) ~=~ \sum_{i=1}^{11} \mathsf P(X_i=1)+0 ~=~ \dfrac {35}{12}$$

---

Alternatively, let $Y_j$ be the indicator that fox $j$ is followed by a hound.   Now we are after $~\mathsf E(\sum_{j=1}^5 Y_j)~$, though this is the same average count as above.

We observe that there are 11 of 12 positions any fox can be followed by something, and when given such a position, 7 of the 11 possible pursuers are hounds.   Thus: $\mathsf E(Y_j)~=~\mathsf P(Y_j=1) ~=~ \tfrac 7{12}$.   Hence by Linearity of expectation we sum over the five foxes:

> $$\mathsf E(\sum_{j=1}^5 Y_j) ~=~ \sum_{j=1}^5 \mathsf P(Y_j=1) ~=~ \dfrac {35}{12}$$

Same answer, different approach.

Comment: Nice double explanation (+1)

Answer (score 5):

Just imagine the foxes and hounds  all placed randomly  in a row, their position won't change when they come out.

Then P(a fox is in **any** position) $=\frac{5}{12}$,

and P(a hound is in **any** position) $= \frac{7}{12}$.

For P(get a fox immediately followed by a hound), the logic is more subtle, the probabilities of a fox-hound pair occupying any  two positions will be the same, hence the same as a fox-hound pair occupying positions $1$ and $2$.

Let $X_i$ be an indicator variable that $= 1$ if a fox-hound pair starts at $i$, and $0$ otherwise.
$P[X_i] =\frac5{12}\cdot\frac7{11} = \frac{35}{132}$

The expectation of an indicator variable is the same as its probability,

> thus $E[X_i] = \frac{35}{132}$

Such fox-hound pairs can start  at

> any of the first $11$ positions,

thus by linearity of expectation,

> $E[X] =  11\cdot\frac{35}{132} = \frac{35}{12}$